# Very weird error in chess __init__.py file

Tags: python, python-typing, python-chess

I import chess in python and I finished everything in the project but when I click run I find a very weird error in file `__init__.py`

the error

```
File "D:\pythonProject\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from typing import ClassVar, Callable, Counter, Dict, Generic, Hashable, Iterable, Iterator, List, Mapping, Optional, SupportsInt, Tuple, Type, TypeVar, Union
ImportError: cannot import name 'Counter'
```

Comment: i am using python 3.6

Comment: There's a lot of type hinting going on in that module!

Comment: @buran It's deprecated but it should still work as an import

Comment: Do you have a module named `typing.py`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands, yes, you right.

Comment: i made copied and pasted the same project in python 3.10 and it works

Comment: `typing.Counter` is new for python 3.5.4 (or 3.6.1? https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Counter), I guess you were using an earlier python 3 version

Comment: Strangely the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Counter) for `typing.Counter` say it was new in **both** version 3.5.4 *and* 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that i need to use a higher version of python i was using python 3.6
and i started using higher version of python like 3.10 and it is working perfectly now